# ReferenceError when using css filter functions with inline styling

Tags: html, css, reactjs, inline-styles

```
<button 
  style={{ filter: sepia(0.5) }}>
  Show results
</button>
```

I get this error: "ReferenceError: sepia is not defined". I know I can fix this by writing css in its own file, but I need to make it work inside jsx to programatically change styles whenever needed.

Comment: You need to wrap that in a string: `filter: 'sepia(0.5)'`.